# PHP return result from a loop

Tags: php, loops

I have a PHP script with a *while* loop and I need to return the result as a **single** variable !

Code schema :

```
$count = "0";
while($count < "4")
{
 echo $count;
 $count = $count + "1";
}
```

It will return : *0123*,
What I want to have a variable with the value : *0123*

I also tried :

```
$count = "0";
while($count < "4")
{
 $result .= $count;
 $count = $count + "1";
}
echo $result;
```

But it will show the result like : *0010120123*

**I know I can use array to get all results outside the loop, but I want to have all results as a single variable but not in an array !**

**Update :
I found the problem :S stupid mistake ! I used :**

```
echo $result
```

Inside my loop :S
So

```
$result .= $count;
```

Work fine :)

Comment: Yes $rresult also print 0123

Comment: You means 01234..... etc ?

Comment: no only 0123 as per Lynxis

Comment: So its printing right ? whats the problem

Comment: @BharatDangar ur right, it work correctly :)

Comment: @Rahul_m yea thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = "0";
$var = "";
while($count < "4")
{
 $var .= $count;
 $count++;
}
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that can do it to you

Pass 4 in the parametrs to match your example

```
function abc($limit){  
    $count = "";
    for($i=0; $i<$limit; $i++)
    { 
         $count .= $i;
    }
    return $count;
}

echo abc(4); // outputs 01234
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should do it:

```
<?php

$count = "0";
$var = "";
while($count < "4")
{
 $var .= $count;
 $count++;
}

echo $var;

?>
```